# Смена адреса iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

После успешной отправки Ajax-запроса в функции `success()` нужно поменять адрес в `<iframe>`и загрузить новую страницу.
Ajax запрос работает хорошо, поэтому приведен лишь небольшой кусок кода. В переменной `new_page` находится новый адрес, который нужно заменить в `</iframe>`.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="result" src="./test/index.html"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
success: function(data) {
    var new_page = "./news/news.html";
    //$('#result').html();      
}
```

Comment: $('#result').attr('src', new_page);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
success: function(data) {
    var new_page = "./news/news.html";
    $('#result').attr('src', new_page);
}
```